# AWS Privileged Access Management?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Understand that AWS has a variety of identity management tools and best practices. However, does AWS offer Privileged Identity/Access Management feature as well?

For example, by default, there is no admin user. If someone wants to assume the admin role, he/she has to submit requests to get necessary approvals from senior management. Then a temporary admin role is assigned to this user for a limited period of time to perform necessary tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create a custom IAM policy and assigned to that user.
Example:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "*",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "DateGreaterThan": {"aws:CurrentTime": "2020-04-01T00:00:00Z"},
            "DateLessThan": {"aws:CurrentTime": "2020-06-30T23:59:59Z"}
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: @Henrix this is Admin access policy.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The IAM policy will set expiry date for the given user. However, my original question is more from a process perspective. If a user wants to get admin rights, he has to request for it, and manager or some "super admin" would approve it. After the approval, your said IAM policy is expected to be created automatically. Then how can this process (request -> approve -> auto enable) be done within AWS? That was my quesion :)

Comment: No that is not possible with AWS currently.